# Adding values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add up the 2 values (bold) that are inputed by the user but instead of adding then mathematically (100+1 = 101) it adds them like this (100+1 = 1001).

```
$('#inputcost').keyup(function(){       
 var price = $(this).val();      
});


function checkboxcost() {
var sum = 0;
var gn, elem;
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
gn = 'extra'+i;
elem = document.getElementById(gn);
if (elem.checked == true) { sum += Number(elem.value); }
}


**var total = (price.value + sum.toFixed(2));
document.getElementById('totalcost').value = "$" + total;**



} 


</script>


<input id="totalcost" disabled/>
```

Comment: You need to use parseInt();

Comment: @Rafael  var total = parseInt(price.value + sum.toFixed(2));
  document.getElementById('totalcost').value = "$" + total;    Like this? All its doing is multiplying the price var by 10.

Comment: var total = (parseInt(price.value) + sum.toFixed(2)); try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as you suspect, in this line:

```
var total = (price.value + sum.toFixed(2));
```

The problem is that `.toFixed` converts the number to a string for display. So you are trying to add a string to a number, which results in concatenation, not addition.

You want to add the numbers together, then display the sum:

```
var total = (price.value + sum).toFixed(2);
```

---

With that said, I'm not sure where `price.value` is coming from, so it's possible that's a string too. In which case, convert it with the [unary plus `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29):

```
var total = (+price.value + sum).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: The 3rd one works, thanks so much!

Comment: So the checkboxes update the total automatically but for the input I have to press the checkbox for it to update. How can I get it so the input updates the total when changed by itself?

Comment: @Dylan12 Probably you want either a `change` or a `keyup` event listener.

Comment: I did use a keyup event. Look at the beginning, its just not working though.

Comment: @Dylan12 But you're not running the `UpdateCost` function on `keyup`.

Comment: the Update Cost function is just to update the check box prices

Answer (score 0):

Its treating price.value as String so convert that string to number like:

```
var total = (Number(price.value) + sum.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Its still just adding together like 100+1 = 1001

Comment: How about if you sum price.value + sum and then ask for two digits after decimal something like `(Number(price.value) + sum).toFixed(2)`?

Comment: So the checkboxes update the total automatically but for the input I have to press the checkbox for it to update. How can I get it so the input updates the total when changed by itself?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the types of the operands are strings and the `+` operator for two strings does concatenation, not addition.

If you convert them to numbers then you'll get a number result:

```
"1" + "2" == "12"

parseFloat("1") + parseFloat("2") == 3
```

Comment: Okay, so whats the difference between parseInt() and parseFloat()?

Comment: `parseFloat("1.1") == 1.1` whereas `parseInt("1.1") == 1`

Answer (score 0):

it seems string addition is taking place.
So try converting string numbers to integer using parseInt() like:

```
var x = parseInt("1")
var y = parseInt("2")
var z = x + y
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `parseInt(price.value) + ...`